# Will I miss anything important if I turn the sound off?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the Dwarf Fortress options menu, the *Music and Sound* option allows you to set the desired volume, however this is a single option that will turn off both music and sound is set to 0.

For the moment I would like to play without the music on, but as a new player, I'm a bit worried that I might miss something important if I do this, like a sound effect indicating that something fun has happened.

Will turning the sound off affect anything other than the music volume?

Comment: Only the great music.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. The only sound in the game is the music. If you turn the sound off, you'll miss nothing beside a guitar track by the creator of the game himself.

Comment: I agree. Sound in dwarf fortress is for relaxating purposes. And don't carry other functions

Comment: +1 I've played through many successful (and some "successful") fortresses without sound.

Answer (score 3):

Turning off the sound *will* affect something other than the music volume – it will skip running the sound code, giving somewhere between an infinitesimally small and a noticeably large speed boost depending on your system.

Of course, I know that's not what you meant to ask, but it is a pedantic answer to what you wrote. ;)

Comment: Are you sure about this? I really doubt that it "skips running the sound code" with the sound off, the computer probably just doesn't power/send signal to the jack.

Comment: @Nick: No, just like video, sound has to be "rendered", which doesn't need to happen when there is no sound. If you'd run an application in console-mode, it would skip over the video rendering, right? Well, good chance the same goes for DF when the sound is turned off.

Comment: Yep. That's what the single option that turns them both off is for. It's not much of a difference, but low-end systems have shown a few FPS of improvement by setting that option to 0.